# Popup coming at the end of HTML element

Tags: javascript, css, angular, bootstrap-modal, ng-idle

I am building angular 4 app with session time out example (ng-idle) where am rendering pop up (bootstrap 3) when user not doing any activity.

`this.idle.onIdleStart.subscribe(() => this.isIdleState = true);`

It is rdering pop when this flag `this.isIdleState = true`.

Problem is pop is showing in end of HTML element of angular application.

Whereas as per bootstrap document it should apper in z-index. For example

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_modal&stacked=h

```
<div *ngIf= isIdleState" >
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4>Session Timeout warning</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          you will be timed out in {{countdown}}
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="reset()">Continue</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<div>
```

Html code in app.compoenent.html so that pop will available on every component.

the way it appear is 
[Pop showing after elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FByy5.png)

I have tried adding z-index property to pop div but that doesn't work  Any help would appreciate.

Comment: Do you want the model to be appeared in middle of the screen on top of the elements?

Comment: @UI_Dev I want modal to appear at top of element. As shown in this example : https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_modal&stacked=h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your modal window not open on button click.You have to make modal visible to do this  try to give inline css display:block; to modal div.

```
<div *ngIf= isIdleState" >
<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" style="display:block;">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4>Session Timeout warning</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      you will be timed out in {{countdown}}
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="reset()">Continue</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have **`modal fade`** class parent div in your modal.

Bootstrap modal will automatically fade the background and open up the modal.

Try to add the parent div with modal fade and give model id as shown below.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modelID" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4>Session Timeout warning</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        you will be timed out in {{countdown}}
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="reset()">Continue</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

And, add `data-target` with same model ID and `data-toggle` attributes to the button as below

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modeID">Open Modal</button>
```

Comment: My Modal window does not invoke based in button click ,  it will appear when this ` <div *ngIf= isIdleState" > `  condition is true. I have used ``` modal fade``` but after using it the modal window not coming at all.